# How to sort a list containing a list of integers according to the sum of their elements

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have already created a list containing a list of integers and I want to sort this list of lists according to the sum of its elements, but actually i have no idea how can i do it ;/

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> listList = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3),
            Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3),
            Arrays.asList(27, 4, 33),
            Arrays.asList(27, 41, 33)
            );

    List<Integer> sumList = listList.stream()
            .sorted((list1, list2) -> {
                int sumlistCompare = Integer.sum()

            })
```

Comment: How should the lists be sorted if two or more of them have the same sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the sum of lists and compare them while sorting as:

```
private int sumOfList(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
}

List<List<Integer>> sumListSort = listList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(SampleClass::sumOfList))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Integer>> sortedListOfLists = listList.stream()
                .sorted((list1, list2) -> {
                    int list1Sum = list1.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                    int list2Sum = list2.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                    return list1Sum - list2Sum;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```